# Is it real to redirect http request like this?

Tags: http

e.g. Main server runs nginx and checks http request hostname. If hostname matches exampleX.com - redirects to needed local server with its own nginx on board. Local server returns page content. Is it real and how can i build this?
[image: scheme]

Comment: Yes you can. You have documentation to read. Example: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: If you prefer the `apache` flavor: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html